# gparted doesn't work with an external hard drive with sector size of 4096

Tags: linux, formatting, hard-drive

When I open **gparted**, I got below:

```
sudo gparted
======================
libparted : 2.2
======================
Device /dev/sdc has a logical sector size of 4096.  Not all parts of GNU Parted support this at the moment, and the working code is HIGHLY EXPERIMENTAL.

Ignoring device /dev/sdc with logical sector size of 4096 bytes because gparted only supports a size of 512 bytes.
```

**/dev/sdc** is the external hard drive (WD Elements 3TB).

It seems **gparted** doesn't work with this hard drive. Any clue?

Answer (score 1):

Try `gdisk` instead. You haven't said which version of Linux you're using, but it should be available.

Note that because your drive is over 2tb you will need to use GPT partitioning.